# Vimdiff : highlight line numbers differently

Tags: highlight, vimdiff, line-numbers

I use relative line numbers thanx to the following settings in my vimrc:

```
set number
set relativenumber
```

Since I don't want to wrap lines in `diff` mode, it's sometimes hard to tell which line include a difference from one buffer to another, when the difference is at the end of a line.

So one could highlight the entire line, but that's not what I want; I also know that there are some bindings to jump from a diff to another, but that's not the purpose of the question.

In `diff` mode, is it possible to use a different highlighting for the line numbers that include a difference? That way, I could immediately know which of the displayed lines include any differences, even if they are at the end of the lines.

Comment: not possible. Perhaps a plugin can mark differences in the sign column

Comment: In diff mode, an entire line including any differences is highlighted in DiffChange. To more focus on the changed line, you might want to try `syntax off` and `set diffopt+=context:0`.

Comment: **@Christian** > Yes, I've looked for such a plugin, but haven't found any... Any idea? **@Rick** > the `context` setting is a good idea. I hadn't thought about it, thanx !